# How to generate SAML SSO for tableau

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, single-sign-on, tableau-api, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement a SAML SSO to my ColdFusion web application and I have read lots of articles but am still unclear on how to generate SAML saml2:EncryptedAssertion.

Now I want to implement SAML SSO in tableau.

I have some confusion on the AES encryption method.

Can anyone tell me how to create the 'CipherValue'? Any suggested documentation related to this?

This is my sample SAML response:

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                Destination="https://sso.online.tableau.com/public/sp/SSO?alias=5e998a7f-34bb-4233-b594-7f0be4ac9a50"
                ID="mdhihkbjpdbflgjjkiokfoachmaaoeheefnpajgi"
                IssueInstant="2020-02-19T13:39:12.264Z"
                Version="2.0"
                >
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://login.xecurify.com/moas/204947/27c493c2-4827-11ea-8bb8-02c931e36dd8</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#mdhihkbjpdbflgjjkiokfoachmaaoeheefnpajgi">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue>SIjM2qZM8H7deBUJTHS16+3e4prO7AWrJcd7/i75d+w=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>jJp82+OTdPQRbLXM36vQ/g9WBoqdbmLK7H8vGTeXFUO8IDaTbyFxfaU/aaHxdmHgH/1Qy8vclYgQsmI7Wx66jfYh2v5Ucy3mCsNcqKFymqz2Kn42gLC2cU3QEJIqPija8Sz1R63RcRoFm8V8My9wu5cDFpeMgY9AR+BqSfsGZBcoLlqVON0syRqHRAOJCUbUxNet1rYNMY308M5AImpfNDcJqXofetkqu7/Lmq9xgPTcMNkh7sqSkXvXiszuB9Ul9ieRVi1yV51NRcFIoFcE/BwB5fU+uhAeQxhXd71ebTPH1o3gl26U/XDYiPpxGM0f6s8JY2MDPmDF6Pnwuftppg==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDGTCCAgGgAwIBAgIJAM49kQYbMHC5MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEwxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMRMw
                    EQYDVQQKEwptaW5pT3JhbmdlMRMwEQYDVQQLEwptaW5pT3JhbmdlMRMwEQYDVQQDEwptaW5pT3Jh
                    bmdlMB4XDTIwMDIwNTE0NTI0MFoXDTMwMDIwMjE0NTI0MFowTDELMAkGA1UEBhMCSU4xEzARBgNV
                    BAoTCm1pbmlPcmFuZ2UxEzARBgNVBAsTCm1pbmlPcmFuZ2UxEzARBgNVBAMTCm1pbmlPcmFuZ2Uw
                    ggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCQeiBR8hjbO0lKn0OX5Ml9ygrNLLA+QFit
                    c0bUTmoSAyLzubrM7Kg7Vg27D7r2itpKUWUA3/fx74+wJrXrDyGWrf1U8DWOCzbCQLNMbfwzdhEJ
                    EV0qVBVNl5RzyvfNaC26rxjRuoZBg+BBzTDBtkJ9K4gwob14XyXNtgoGyislIrLZnlGV40uzu17T
                    VySOZMPl3B3ImirAaVFYkx6ZZTgUrDsyI+VXtF020CbFN+oNGW+2nsx4/Z4uSlOUU9E0z1yceHrw
                    Y+ShPD1/U9WZOih42zL24o/rvJlcovs81x+6zkdKTUgmnf7BAdW06u10VIJqCyAut9LqJBAGSik/
                    yVeLAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAADG7omHudMFRDATY9mBW+mt+P0QESrfJ1QlzdED
                    8nU/s6S7i62R/t/zrJLgAYozzDNXnBi04ROWV2Qk05N9iMH4XDiAtTuEEhWsVkdsRqoBurn42WtP
                    nKgz55phoe6Sfg0UsSyfgnEi+Ks46QZXwG9evHtOCZglBV8sqepHPGWXRXGx2oG6EEXgqb/rSdtY
                    D3NtnIZQWk+gl0LDmxN5pju0mTbMipJgMNr1QyZNa0mm6sTJy3eBSmFiGVa0nMDlM6NXyLPMovef
                    EKYeFU8XL6SBQICYEDeeMdw/x1ycbwa16DC2EUvX3MMsF2JGoRKmLTnaorIxZ7N9/vuDr1BBEV0=</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                            Id="_b046db603bd493b9b67eab9afbeb6031"
                            Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                            >
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"
                                   xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                   />
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="_3c3857a5ed5cbfdf1bda23ffd5f31023"
                                   xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                   >
                    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"
                                           xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                           >
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
                                         xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                                         />
                    </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
                    <ds:KeyInfo> 
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                    <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                        <xenc:CipherValue>Q7e4Qf00jex6kp7/LIHI6eiMs+0jP5o6+jNH0LHjMFJsxdcwb5arsjyKpH9baQVTAKoKGF/wuASKSXuJhXBInEC6c3bD6qdJ1BLlwQJi4hYC7KUplknEXHO1fp1VawGRfux16sQbgPEwznqk0bp8+MPyhdlAkJajr2COtSe8eNU=</xenc:CipherValue>
                    </xenc:CipherData>
                </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:CipherValue>1uxYnQtirg8YBc48iJC5yiRKjpZjZ/HfNAm4xk+YGyd/RwkLIx3DDxpgT470gGp9C7ybr+G107oLlDOyI836WqqbaX74ibNKmcd1MuT4ghLEzHi6FSCCBjb6Rgw8/rnOaoxrkS9LrEju1HZWJgFBqoMOP0kNpswYIKAZQ50GKY/WJz2lWMM/jiV0wNzCPv5PdMPhNHEAwRTi5rFFw9sskroXSXv2TiWQaX1poiTb/Zt3iIJVtqOGjzyX3nn/HLu/qn9aS3yUOA7Dl4K3hL587cLHy/KJQyJq95RNYUyu//tRE1TTUIcT71aPLwfotGdQUHOuCh3gZ2MrxB3CF42JpAE5k8MdQkHjUAX9l/44amn2X9zIDcG8D84Fxan0cNDtXwXOUtpWTeyormMphVUbq+St/dWT7HWBv9vKSmAlgLQAN+XJmnw3ZFjDr/u+mbh5wcReZvfghVcLfQmBIqTrevNF44R3TEZ45J5Je0X7InVK/Er/spyfBT1fnhAJCIXQsYWsQDiFMAAKSBs+6JatGfYBvNx27ZS3KsnxW9oHRsqJBkEMcBcTnqGhbunUDVx1V5iSwl/sNKHXFeplNo+wiSL9na1QmplomUYkN/lj/wujSlz2kmcUcG13XDXtebF8DIDMIsPHUrQoshKrxf45Zej+/FDaxnkcsdwkah/3NZDFH4VUEETsg1XqRNJgoxTdq/lYyzlbpsrY8ppmw0BVFYXURXu5cq0RAyEAcKcQoF/NQc5sueAWqZgaTDZ/10aOtOAyqpxdlou25EDbDffDCrtZ1hTsPN6Dfek+YBmwjNlJ9ncVvqZzou6ANyiHxZyZI9PEm4QUEy/U9HBfPfHVIuFpGuHw5xm0u3SbD37ChgeKV0CymWLj6hb3Xu3INtwwJJfP0Xr2atercv25FfFG5LbSDZwDEToAF2gHaH8xxnPsWDfRe2aFPh7qa/GEzrqfzZE4TlEyVkuOQXygbygKOHYT8bogkUSuoTPjf/jd8LHFcBj2yL3eG1sPspwCZayFVWPTOSXlK133elqWasNtmy2rSXGGq3/jNvFAdaOMUXXLo0iNV1VCI7OIXu+EpQ2I15mrwv9YXI4nFgqI7E/hih5B4Gssw4m78lwJMTgiISfOLEmVBgNMU01sAYN91syIKLRIknIfsFANCls2htoay88sboJEntw5gsHyjKw9TDAyRBEKVDGMdyTivYgj2bYTC2nKB6blLANOLLhY1uRgzPudeXbQDg7x4eHN/tzSMlhI6zHTBjtkD5JtApcZfhGSzOa3Z1/0ZKtciK0BurjpL0X8r+MqE3R8H7ssZs4emOZoQFyrouQTp/ABNErcQHdcNr/QAbIH9MlzQNups3esgkpbKSw/sAjE+dOWgdN/N5faLGEXqFLhvdrRA123nO71ncFNy2ZgcM0NirK3buS4ll7TmTjAAMZpoTMGy3PBsSx2h611aVXB4ET5aKtb0VL8F4oleTt2GCqR6RfJf1WbisZqPbobPNFVBDHOWrbCstmwA41xy+ohxNCcBtG2TNG+NrSR0+aisQvaMLE39bkai1xBL0d8pu4FPhDgn9SaPQV8PCyh/en+fEXuVDs+upUrG3HKiOeyP8BtUyHIQ4ReVGbuO237twOQ1D86LoxNLwBkfUI3YvFP8kpdQ8ifB5CB19VN6Q6aqYi8/SP37HVgUrZxszNbLFhC5QQDSQSoQla5olc25vPTAncQYosCWjmsBp8H1B+YxP7R2uzbhk7bnNINMSnBQ/KZqLSGlYMx+AHCBlMI2KE9rGevPGT4K5z9M437Ap6tQZOCNNhvahDTogN+viW71Da+G6emCZXfwosMEw8ive/5TRiQZkhNKVcs4yAQ4z5f96TojC6RB7aekWM122gxvc8veKxPEER6KHEBsn6LuYfYFHNdygIRQX1J5wPG+3WgjiyUnIt8NmbU3uXoGhySGVvKzk9Avrz2/7MkgUyPy8B0VScIVMAXO+1MxTctbYk3zWYr/h4a/d7cCKVgtfp11yCW606xDqWnOOfyvlc4ph1J28rh4OFDlFd1dvbIzpAr6uEz9ZumV7NXQgevgabtX5kI1m42JmK7YojvItFEJ1WM17s4MKJZXl5YKmyevmPjH9hdXI/m4wR8GuMLXDtk29vRERl83vcvOJUzB+/oIydzB647OoOoRNPjjp25hV5RYnGhrkBuBq8zpQKq/Nl5mfdB8i8ocabvnmdhOv5ZHYZ77ZPmkZijNpKSvHN4l9GswhfhBjVZjgqj1qoBsv7tyD7GuhN7ggp5Q8eZsSC0h/IZ3AzR0Adc4ROapMk3d4fO3OkeqCm368QW2DA2HhB3Rs9Qr6LjdH5dvdMY4NUKehEfAHho/wf7RNKobGzkZTNXvH6lAeeCldfEOMVnmwZPN0s9SZAOuNLGb2I=</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: You should be able to gain some insight into how to accomplish this by searching on this site. [Try this search to begin](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=coldfusion+saml)

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Online (the hosted version) does not support encrypted assertions. Excerpt from [SAML requirements](https://help.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/saml_online_requ.htm) of Tableau Online:

> **SP or IdP initiated**: Tableau Online supports SAML authentication that
>   begins at the identity provider (IdP) or service provider (SP).
>
> **Cleartext assertions**: Tableau Online does not support encrypted
>   assertions.

You need to turn off encrypting of the assertion in your  SAML identity provider.